# XSLT Template Match 'middle' child

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and was wandering how to match the 'middle' child/sibling nodes? (so basically all those which are not first or last)

For example, say i have the following xml....

```
<FRUITS>
  <FRUIT>Apple</FRUIT>
  <FRUIT>Pear</FRUIT>     <!--I want to match this in a template-->
  <FRUIT>Banana</FRUIT>   <!--I want to match this in a template-->
  <FRUIT>..........</FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
```

The example above is just a very short example of the xml i am working on. However in the real xml i will never know how many fruit siblings there are. So in other words i am looking to construct a statement that will identify if a node has following-siblings and preceding-siblings together. I have looked at the following but no joy as the syntax is not correct.....

```
<xsl:template match="FRUIT[preceding-sibling::FRUIT*]/[following-sibling::FRUIT*]" />
```

And also....

```
<xsl:template match="FRUIT[preceding-sibling::FRUIT*] and [following-sibling::FRUIT*]" />
```

This is using XSLT 1.0

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, use `match="FRUIT[preceding-sibling::FRUIT and following-sibling::FRUIT]"`.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, glad to see i was almost there at least, but still got a lot to learn.

Comment: Just to ask something further, is it possible to to match a specific FRUIT node if it has more than 1 following-sibling, for example I am looking to execute...<xsl:template match="FRUIT[following-sibling::FRUIT >1]" />. This however does not seem to work, i am pretty sure this is not constructed properly

Comment: Consider to start with a tutorial or book on XSLT and XPath, then you will have more success writing your code. If you use `match="FRUIT[count(following-sibling::FRUIT) > 1]"` or `match="FRUIT[following-sibling::FRUIT[2]]"` then you have a pattern matching `FRUIT` elements having at least two following sibling elements of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

you can also check for first and last position

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/FRUITS/FRUIT"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FRUIT[position() != 1 and position() != last()]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @PhillyNJ for your suggestion, the use of the position functions is still rather unknown to me so nice to see an example of those being utilised